# Leveraging Concurrent future functionality on a simple function

Tags: python, pandas, concurrency, parallel-processing, concurrent.futures

I have a simple function which takes in 4 arguments which are all data frames, using those data frames it does pre-processing like cleaning, using Machine Learning to fill in null values, manipulate the data frames using group by and then in the end gives out two data frames in the return function.
Something like this:

```
def preprocess(df1,df2,df3,df4):
    "some arguments for cleaning and manipulation data" 
    return(clean,df_new)
```

Since i am performing memory intensive operations, I was thinking if I can utilize the concurrent futures functionality in python. I did try simply using this style:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
 executor.map(clean,df_new=preprocess(df1,df2,df3,df4))
```

I am getting error saying that clean and df_new is not defined. I am a bit confused about how to use concurrent future on "preprocess" function so that I can utilize all the cores of my laptop and fasten the processing speed for this operation. Any ideas/help is really appreciated.

Comment: What do clean and df_new represent here, and why are you returning them? It is complaining that they aren't defined because... well... they aren't.

Comment: Please see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map) the way you are *calling* `.map` does not match the call signature in the documentation.

Comment: @EvanHessler they are just the output of the function. So the function pre-process is doing data cleaning and pre-processing and after everything is done it converts those four input dataframes into 2 namely clean and df_new which I return so that I can use them for further purpose.

Comment: `...Executor.map` maps a function on multiple inputs.  Your function as written requires 4 arguments and it does not appear that concurrent.futures will help.

Comment: @wwii so if not concurrent, is there any other way I can speed up the processing? I am just trying to figure out how to fasten the speed of processing of the functions which take time. Is there any other way?

Comment: Gotcha. Well you can't return 'clean' and 'df_new' before you define what they represent. The computer can't abstract that for you. But that is a separate issue from your concurrency question. Does all of your preprocessing happen on your CPU? In that case, concurrency won't help you.